# Get Database values based on linq query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have created a linq query to check if an item exists in the database table, that works just fine. 
Now I would like to get the value out of the table and put in into unitOfMeasure.

```
string quantityUomIngredient = request.Form.Get("QuantityUomIngredient");
string[] quantityUomIngredientArray = quantityUomIngredient.Split();

string uom = quantityUomIngredientArray[1];
int unitOfMeasure;
bool checkUOM = (from x in db.UnitOfMeasures where x.Abbreviation == uom select x).Count() > 0;
if (checkUOM)
    {
    unitOfMeasure = from x in db.UnitOfMeasures
                    where x.Abbreviation == uom
                    select x.UnitOfMeasureId;
    }
```

How can I get this value out of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FirstOrDefault

```
unitOfMeasure = (from x in db.UnitOfMeasures
                    where x.Abbreviation == uom
                    select x.UnitOfMeasureId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.First`

```
unitOfMeasure = (from x in db.UnitOfMeasures
                    where x.Abbreviation == uom
                    select x.UnitOfMeasureId).First<int>();
```